# ajax redirect after successful login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I have been all over the internet trying to figure this one out.  I am trying to add a jquery dialog window that will call an action to login a user and then upon successful login, redirect the user to their profile page, otherwise keep the dialog window open and prompt the user with the appropriate error message.  Up to this point, the login part seems to work but when the action returns it keeps the user on the same page.  What changes do I need to make to determine a successful login and redirect appropriately?  Here is my code:

```
"Javascript code"
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#LogOnForm');
$('#LogOnDialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false, width: 450, height: 300, modal: true,
     buttons: {
        'Log On': function () {
            if ($('#LogOnForm').validate().form()){
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("LogOnPartial", "Account")',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: $('form').serialize(),
                        datatype: 'json',
                        success: function (result) {
                            $('#LogOnDialog').html(result).dialog('open');
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            Cancel: function () { 
                $(this).dialog('close'); 
            }
        }
    });




    $('#linkSignIn').live('click', function () {
        $('#LogOnDialog').html('')
        .dialog('option', 'title', 'Sign In')
        .load('@Url.Action("LogOnPartial", "Account")', function () { $('#LogOnDialog').dialog('open'); });
    });



    "Controller Action"
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOnPartial(LogOnModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            UserPrincipal principal = new UserPrincipal(model.EmailAddress, model.Password);
            HttpContext.User = principal;
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.EmailAddress, true);
            return PartialView("LogOnPartial", model);
        }

        return PartialView("LogOnPartial", model);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how you want to achieve this but on you result you most likely want to return the id of the user of which profile you want to login.

```
   success: function (result) {
                           if(result=='')/// no result show the dialog again 
                            {
                             $('#LogOnDialog').html(result).dialog('open');
                            }
                            else // redirect to profile page 
                            {
                                 window.location = 'profile/'+result;   
                            }
                    }
                });
```

your action can be something like

```
    public ActionResult ProvinceFilter(LogOnModel model)
    {
      string result=="";    
      UserPrincipal principal = new UserPrincipal(model.EmailAddress, model.Password); //in order to retorn exact error you must modify the principle to check if the user is valid or not and return specific error
     if(principal==null) //or not valid 
      {
         result="Your Username or Password is not correct";
      }
      else
       {
        HttpContext.User = principal;
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.EmailAddress, true);
        result=principal.UserID.ToString();
       }
        return Json(result);
    }
```

Comment: What should my action look like to differentiate between the two scenarios?

Comment: you need to use ajax action/json return

Comment: Judging from my action above, should I return this whether or not the ModelState.Valid is true or false?  If it is false I want the user to see the modal panel with some error message letting them know what they did wrong, invalid user/pass combination, etc, otherwise perform the redirect.

Comment: you can, but I would just return a pure error message from the action

Comment: could you change the Action I have above to match how it should look if I am returning an error message?  Having trouble picturing how it should look for my ActionResult above.

Comment: How should my action change below to reflect this scenario?  Here is the code     below:

    "Controller Action"
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOnPartial(LogOnModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            UserPrincipal principal = new UserPrincipal(model.EmailAddress, model.Password);
            HttpContext.User = principal;
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.EmailAddress, true);
            return PartialView("LogOnPartial", model);
        }

        return PartialView("LogOnPartial", model);
    }